# jQuery slider messing up my css gradient?

Tags: jquery, css, gradient

I put a jQuery slider in my page, and when I add a new `div` underneath it and add `float: left` the gradient stops right there. Here's the [LINK](http://oncreation.nl/temp/seekprev/).

And when I don't add `float: left` the gradient background is normal :s...

**CSS:**

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    margin:0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: 'AandachtBold';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    background: #cdd6de;!important;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#f4f5f5), to(#cdd6de));fixed !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f5f5, #cdd6de);fixed !important;
    background: linear-gradient(#f4f5f5, #cdd6de);fixed !important;
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#f4f5f5, #cdd6de);fixed !important;
    behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/smooth-src-comments.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'img/loading.gif',
            play: 3500,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: in what browser do you have the problem?

Comment: I looked at it in safari, firefox and chrome on my macbook....

Comment: edit: the problem im only seeing in safari and chrome, there's a white and green div. The green div is the one with float left. And is also  not showing in firefox....

Comment: could you post this at jsfiddle with a link please?

and, you should have only one semi-colon closing your css properties, that might be causing a problem.

Comment: Sorry can you explain your last sentence? English kinda bad here...

Comment: @Andre Dublin My CSS was bad, i think you meant semi-colon with this thing here ;. It solved it. BIG Thanks!!

Comment: could you post this at jsfiddle with a link please?

and, you should have only one semi-colon closing your css properties, that might be causing a problem.

Comment: @Andre Dublin 

I think you meant semi-colon with this thing here ;. It solved it!
(My coding was a bit messy.)

BIG Thanks!! A friend who was helping me said exactly the same thing at exactly the same time:p



Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css code seems to be invalid.

For example

```
  background: #cdd6de;!important;
```

This should be like so

```
  background: #cdd6de !important;
```

Also I have never seen **"fixed"** used on a gradient before, this could be causing a problem

```
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f5f5, #cdd6de);fixed !important;
```

---

Try using my code below with your colors, this code works in Internet Explorer too;

```
  background: #0A284B;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0A284B), to(#135887));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0A284B, #135887);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0A284B', endColorstr='#135887');
  zoom:1;
```

Comment: Thanks!! I was wondering why the gradient didn't work in IE. Learning allot about coding these couple of days. Im more of an designer but its still fun. (: